# How to make a python delete script recursive?

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

I found the following Python script here on Stack Overflow. I got it to work without issue except that I need to be recursive meaning that it will delete subfolders/files as well. How can I do that?

```
#Import the required Python modules
import os
import time
import sys

#Set the folder path for deletion
path = r"c:\Delete"

#Set the time variable for "now" to subtract 30 days from "now."
now = time.time()

#Loop through the files in the path and delete any older than 30 days!
for f in os.listdir(path):
     f = os.path.join(path, f)
     if os.stat(f).st_mtime < now - 30 * 86400:
          if os.path.isfile(f):
               os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're using the term *recursive* in your title, so I will assume you know what it means and realize the top-level code you posted cannot be recursive -- only functions can. So, I would start by refactoring that code accordingly, then apply recursivity to the resulting function.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: You can apply recursive logic without using recursive functions. Often they go together, but not always. In this case, it's the directory traversal that needs to be recursive.

Comment: @Blckknght, depends on how you interpret the question, I guess. Anyway, the questioner has to understand what recursion is before they try either way.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and the attempt to assist. However that just leaves me even more confused. But I do apologize if I used incorrect terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`os.walk(path)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) instead of `os.listdir(path)` will do the same, but recursively. Try that.

And of course you will have to get the full path of the files in the subfolders, see the last example in the section I linked to:

```
os.path.join(root, name)
```

Where `root` is the first element in the 3-tuple returned from `os.walk()` and `name` is the third).

**EDIT:** Full example here (taken from the linked page):

```
# Delete everything reachable from the directory named in "top",
# assuming there are no symbolic links.
# CAUTION:  This is dangerous!  For example, if top == '/', it
# could delete all your disk files.
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
  for name in files:
    os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
  for name in dirs:
    os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Just add your time filtering and I think it should work.

Comment: @Ouroborus - I tried but since I am new to StackOverflow it will not show until I reach a reputation of 15. This is a great forum but some of the rules seem to be counter productive. For instance since I am new I was unable to comment on a previous post which I borrowed code from. This forced me to create a new topic when it was not needed! I understand the use of the reputation system but it certainly has disadvantages.

Comment: @toolfan2k4 that's a bit strange, you should be able to accept an answer to your own question even without a minimum reputation?

Comment: @ToVine it says that once I get a reputation of 15 it will post. Honestly I looked at the reputation system and I seriously do not see myself getting 15 points anywhere in the near future especially given that this question already has been down voted twice. At any rate that is not your fault so thanks for the assistance I greatly appreciate it!